# Java cascading JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, cascade

I have a class that extends javax.swing.JFrame built with NetBeans GUI editor.
Is there a way to make this JFrame cascade when several of it being opened ?

Comment: Unless you spawn the multiple frames from within the same program you may need to look into process id's or window titles which may involve native libraries.

Comment: @Onca Are you opening the different frames from the same JVM or one at a time?

Comment: From the same JVM, all together.

Comment: Since it seems you have not only chosen an answer that breaks from the X-plat behavior, and only works for a single JVM, I will add..  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a variable with the previous such opened `JFrame` location and for the next one do:

```
newFrame.setLocation(previousLocation.x + constant, previoudLocation.y + constant);
```

The `getLocation()` will return you the location on screen of an existing `JFrame`.

Comment: OP may have meant multiple instances of the application, ie. not from within the same JVM.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`setLocationByPlatform(true)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556).

[image]

Comment: Note this method should work the same irrespective of same/different JVM.

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame`s are top-level components, they don't nest.

If you need nested frames (i.e. frames that can be a child of another frame), use [JInternalFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) instead.

If you need to create new frames in the existing application when it is invoked again, use a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) to send the arguments for the new frame from the new application to the existing one and then exit the new application.

Comment: Re. last paragraph.  If the app. is launched using JWS it could use the `SingleInstanceService` as seen in [this demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#sis).